# 2 keys search algorithm in O(n)

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, complexity-theory

i have to find an algorithm to sort an array in O(n) complexity.
The array has the length n with two different keys.

For example this array in java:

```
int[][] array = {{1,2},{2,1},{1,1}};
```

The result should be

```
1 1
1 2
2 1
```

I struggle with solving this problem..

Who might be able to  help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `number = digit1 * 10 + digit2`

Comment: Sorting in general cannot be doen in O(n), are there any constraint on the data?

Comment: [Sorting algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm).

Comment: Specifically, [Radix sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort). Your *k* is a constant 2, reducing the complexity to O(n).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data is stored in a [Trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie), then a DFT (Depth First Traversal) will show you how your trie is actually Radix-sorted by definition.

If you've build the Trie, and all sub-sets have the same number of elements, then leaves of the trie are the subsets in order, where the depth of leaves is number of elements per sub-set.

Using a Trie, you have O(m) where m = number of sub-sets

Or you can try a Radix Sort, where you have Ω(n * m) where n = size of a sub-set

..hope this helps